# nano: no version information available

Tags: symbolic-link, nano

The more I try to fix this problem the worse it gets. I have conda installed, and I think its related to this problem. Every time I try to open nano, I get this error message - before today it was only the 3 & 4 lines, but my attempts to fix it have worsened the problem. From what I can tell around here it is an issue with bad symlinks?

```
nano: libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by nano)
nano: libtinfo.so.6: no version information available (required by nano)
nano: /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by nano)
nano: /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6: no version information available (required by nano)
nano: symbol lookup error: /usr/local/lib/libncursesw.so.6: undefined symbol: _nc_tiparm
```

I have tried reinstalling libncurses6, it is already installed with no issues.

```
libncursesw6 is already the newest version (6.2-0ubuntu2).
```

I honestly would just wipe the system and reinstall Ubuntu at this point, but there are some other complicating factors going on - its a server with slurm installed, newer versions of Ubuntu break the slurm install, I don't have weeks to mess around with it. Any help is appreciated.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

and reinstalling initramfs-tools from .deb

and

```
sudo apt-get install -f linux-image-generic
sudo apt-get install -f linux-firmware
```

Ubuntu info:

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

Comment: Hello. The first thing you many want to do is update upgrade as you are running 20.04.3 and an up to date system is 20.04.4